# Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional Randomly Opens a PDF on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, pdf, adobe, adobe-acrobat

I have a Windows 2008 server serving as a terminal server for a small team. The server randomly opens the same PDF file "consistently sometimes" when you double-click another PDF. Both PDFs open.

- This happens for multiple users.
- This has been happening for months.
- This doesn't happen when you open Acrobat itself (from a shortcut)
- This doesn't happen every time you open a PDF, but frequently.

I've tried Googling this to no avail. I really have no idea where to begin. Short of "renaming or moving the PDF that opens", does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have virus scanning software in place?  I know that one of the PDF exploits out there will open certain PDF documents that look legitimate but aren't, they contain exploit code in them.  If someone opened an infected document on the server that could be the cause.  If not, then I don't know.

Here's a link to a video from F-Secure that demonstrates these types of attacks.  They believe that may have been how Google was attacked recently.

http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00001854.html